# How to get the value of the cell from np.where() instead of True/False

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hi I am trying to get my code to print the value of the cell in the column "Position" so that for example if the previous cell in "Position" is long it should also put long until it says Short based on the column "Signal" which will return either buy or sell or "None". However, when I do this what I actually get is True or False im assuming based on the "Long" or Short" but I am new to this so I could be mistaken. The code does what I want in that it correctly picks if we are long or short however instead of returning True or False I would like it to return "Long" or "Short" the value in the cell above (talking about when I convert it to a csv here).

```
df["Position"] = np.where(df['Signal'].ne("None"),np.where(df[f'Signal'].eq("Buy"), "Long", "Short"), np.where(df["Position"].shift(1).ne("None"), df["Position"].shift(1), "None"))
```

Answer (score 0):

np.where() returns the indices where the condition is true. You can use these indices to get the values at those positions. Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0])
mask = np.where(a > 1)
values = a[mask]

>>array([2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: How would you select the first element of that array?

Comment: I'm not sure which one you mean, but i guess this: `a[mask][0]`

Comment: sorry I mean say I want to make it dynamic so something like Mask[:72]

for reference this is the array i get (array([  72,  135,  193,  197,  203,  360,  374,  407, ....]